# Creating a ASP.NET web service, not WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, tcp

I would like to have a client application and web application (or service, no UI) and I would like to connect to said web service from within my desktop application and to have two simultaneous network stream, one of them for uploading data and reading them on server and the other one for sending stuff to the client application.

I am not looking for a solution that uses anything more than that like WCF or anything, I just want a way to create connection between web server and my client application and exchange pure binary data. I would implement the protocol myself, I am not looking for any entities or encapsulation like WCF provides.

I don't even know what project type is the best choice here. I thought about empty ASP.NET application maybe that I'd upload on FTP but I have no idea what I should do next to make the application connectible to. I am not asking for complete solution of course, rather some articles that focus on how to make a plain and simple connection between server and client. I want server to be able to immediately update client and vice versa, that's why I am looking for a way to have stream.

Edit: I may as well say that the service is meant to be placed on ASP.NET hosting and I don't know how ports work on these, if there are any restrictions or anything.

Comment: I would suggest you to read on full duplex channels and net.tcp bindings in wcf. you'll be surprised. WCF is extremely convinient and flexible framework which will allow you to abstract from transport layer.

Comment: @vittore I will look into it, thanks, but from what I read about it on MSDN it seems quite complicated considering I want nothing more but a way to send and receive data simultaneously.

Comment: and exactly in this case WCF will SAVE you a lot of time, as setting up two-way channel in WCF really easy. Of course you can use .NET remoting, but WCF makes your life really easy. Consider reading http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101626.do this book, it is old one but still excellent way to master WCF skills

Comment: Thanks for book recommendation, I will read it and then try again, I can see I seriously lack knowledge here so I am going to study and try easy stuff first before I get to something more complex.

Answer (score 1):

"Web service" and "Network stream" are incompatible concepts. Web-services are (ideally) stateless and disconnected - so they work regardless of how the underlying network works. Messages are exchanged only from client-to-server and are encapsulated in HTTP request/response pairs. Hence "web service".

If you want to exchange "pure binary data" (as you put it) then you just need to work with sockets (or use .NET's TcpClient, which wraps up sockets in an easier-to-use API). ASP.NET would be inappropriate for this.

You can technically have an application that uses sockets that runs within an ASP.NET host process but this might not work depending on how security is set-up and it's also bound by the ASP.NET process lifecycle (so it is activated by IIS and can be shut-down or recycled at any time without warning).

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. But let's consider and internet messenger for example. The is one server and multiple clients and now I wonder would ASP .NET hosting be suitable for such a server application? Or is it better to setup own server that has special Windows service running in it? Because I don't really feel like setting up my home server so I'd like to know if it's possible to maintain uninterrupted connection with ASP .NET webhosting server.

Comment: As I said, it wouldn't be appropriate because (ideally) HTTP and web services that run on top are "stateless", whereas a chat or instant-message server is not stateless. If you were hoping to build a chat service then you'd need to get a dedicated server rather than a simple webhosting account.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the MVC4 [APIController](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/05/introduction-to-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx). It works much like stock MVC except that methods return XML or JSON (or anything else you like).

Eg

`/api/Users/Get`

would could return something like

```
{
    {"Username":"Bob", "Id":3},
    {"Username":"Steve", "Id":4}
}
```

You can also return files and other streams by using special return types. You even get strongly typed, validated input through the use of models.

There's an [example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP) which shows a full CRUD controller and sample AJAX calls from JS which you can replicate in your desktop app

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I can see it uses entities and works over HTTP which I initially didn't want but it seems like there is no easy way for initiating and maintaining connection with web server meant for web hosting. Thanks again.

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem is that web servers were designed to deal with HTTP traffic. You don't really want a webserver at all, you want a server. Can I suggest you look into Microsoft's Azure platform or possibly Amazon's EC2. They would both allow you to get a service up relatively cheaply (I believe MS will be cheaper but slightly _less_ like you're used to as Amazon offers whole servers and MS offers a platform which runs code)

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use ASP.NET Web Services for this (ASMX). That is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development.

Why do you not want to use WCF? Do you believe it's too complicated? The thing about WCF is that it *removes* the complication of creating your own protocols.

Also, which version of .NET are you using? WCF get a lot easier to configure with .NET 4.0.

Comment: I have only a little experience with WCF, I have created one project utilizing WCF so far and it only returned entities with FKs from SQL database using WCF service. But I find it very bloated for just exchanging binary or simple textual data.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you found bloated. You may very well have been doing something wrong. I suggest you try something simple, then ask questions about any "bloat" you see.

Comment: What I meant is I only want a network stream I could write to and read from. But as you can see I don't really know a lot about networking and I guess trying to host server to connect to on web-hosting would complicate things a bit. As you said, I am going to try something simple and see, thanks for you answer!

Comment: I recommend you look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info, and start off by creating a WCF service by just using "Add New Project" and choosing "WCF Service Application". Then make a client that consumes that service. Make no changes to the service and just make it work. _Then_ start making little changes to the service (and client), until you're more comfortable. Be sure to search [so] first, but ask more questions if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple [duplex example](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/48/posts/10054/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf.aspx) using WCF.
Try it, check if performance you've got is enough, try to use alternative bindings ( like net.tcp). WCF is really neat tool to use. Once become more familiar with it you will love it.

Also check chapter on bindings in WCF from [Learning WCF](http://books.google.com/books?id=-AUyj6S7etwC&lpg=PP1&dq=learning%20wcf&pg=PA160#v=onepage&q=learning%20wcf&f=false)